# Desktop icons changed size after a hard shutdown and won't change back

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons

This is what my desktop looked like before

[image: Desktop 1]

And this is what it looks like now

[image: Desktop 2].

I tried to make them as small as possible, but it doesn't work. The icons in the folders look the same as the desktop. I was running a steam game and I clicked away from it and it froze.

I tried to wait for it, but the second time my mouse was gone. I was running an update, so I waited for that to finish and then I manually forced a restart. After that, my icons were bigger, so I scrolled out, and they were still really big.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer! Nautilus recently had an update that enlarged the icons, and that may be what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the Launcher icons, go to **System Settings** > **Appearance**. Move the slider to set the **Launcher icon size** to whatever value you find comfortable.

---

For the desktop icons, try the following:

1. open a folder (any folder)
2. go to menu -> **preferences** in the file explorer
3. change default zoom level

This should propagate to all folders.

Comment: it is my desktop icons not my launcher icons

Comment: Sorry, I was just testing the 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: for some reason, it says that it is the smallest size it can go, but it is still really big.